# Accidentally deleted APNS certificate

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

A week ago, I accidentally deleted APNS certificate on Apple Member Center.

Now, currently running app could not receive notification from server.

I have already made new certificate, updated `.pem` file to server, submitted new version of our app to Apple Store.
It is 3 days after submitting but there is no response from Apple Store yet.

My customer is getting angry because his users could not receive any notification.
Is there any way to restore/upload deleted certificate to Apple Member Center?

Thank you alot

Comment: You shouldn't need to do a new submission for push problem. The APNS certiicate is not used by the app.

Comment: APNS creation required a `certSigningRequest`. Does `.certSigningRequest` file has any meaning? I thought building app also required this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to rebuild the app and submit it to appstore again just to replace APNs certificate, it's absolutely not required. You just needed to produce new APNs certificate using standard process (with Keychain) and replace dead certificate file on your server.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I downloaded `.cer` file from member center, converted it to `.pem` file then replaced `.pem` file on our server.

Is that enough?

While building (archiving) ios project for store deploy submission, there was a warning if I didn't include APNS certificate (from member center).

Does it mean that ios app need Apple certificate to receive notification

Comment: you do code sign of your app with your Distribution certificate - it's enough for submission. ANPs certificate is separate entity. your app and APNs are connected via APP id.

Comment: I also recreated new distribution certificate. Is it a fatal mistake?

I recreated APNS certificate and replaced current file on server, but notification still not coming